# How to secure RESTful calls from Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, rest, restful-authentication

I have a Silverlight application that I am sending/receiving sensitive data to some WCF RESTful endpoints. I know that someone can reverse engineer the Silverlight application to gain any keys so encryption/decryption might not be an option.

Are there any ways to secure the data apart from using HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also try RIA services if you don't need to expose the services to anyone else or this is on the same server.

Comment: This seemed like the best solution for our Silverlight apps.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty, just depends on how much work you want to do. You can use signing via x509, encryption of the message using x509, request restriction (only allow access from xyz domain or ip) or a combination of all/some of those options.

Some of those will be less secure then others givin silverlight can be reversed so you might try obfuscation on your silverlight app.

Comment: I was worried this would be the only option. I feel the best option is to configure my WCF RESTful services to support both HTTP and HTTPS connections and force the HTTPS connection for my Silverlight applications and use a HTTP connection for non-Silverlight applications.

Comment: Why not have your public endpoints as a service and use RIA serives as Titan2782 suggested? This way you don't have to worry about encryption from silverlight to your service and still have your public end points available for consumption.